# Session clearing after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to retain the selected value of a dropdown list after a post back. Each time the post back is completed, I'm hit with a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. It doesn't look like Session is holding SelectedBuyerIndex - any idea why? Thank you!

In Page_Load:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    buyerList = sql.GetBuyersList();

    foreach (Buyer buyerName in buyerList)
        cboBuyers.Items.Add(buyerName.BuyerName);
}
else
{
    cboBuyers.SelectedIndex = (int)Session["SelectedBuyerIndex"]; // error line
}
```

In cboBuyers_SelectedIndexChanged:

```
Session["SelectedBuyerIndex"] = cboBuyers.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: Possibly it is not issue of `Session` variable. Problem may be the dropdown list becomes null. Where you populate `cboBuyers`?

Comment: Do you have the AutoPostBack="true" or "false" in the combo's markup?

Comment: @HassanNisar - when I get the error and hover over `cboBuyers` it does not appear to be null but `Session.Keys.Count` is 0, which I think is the problem if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @lrb - AutoPostBack is true

Comment: Session variable is created when dropdownlist fires SelectIndexChanged. Do you change the index of dropdown list?

Comment: Not through code, no. On the page I do

Comment: Apply a breakpoint and check whether session variable gets a value or not.

Comment: Oh wow it doesn't seem to be. I put a breakpoint at the end of SelectedIndexChanged and the line above marked as // error line gives me a null error still, without stopping at the breakpoint. So it looks like Page_Load is being called before SelectedIndexChanged is... shouldn't that not happen? I thought it would go SelectedIndexChanged -> Post Back -> Page_Load

Comment: @duckwizzle, PageLoad event triggers first and then the control events. So in the page load event check for null of the session variable

Comment: It works now... sort of. It looks like the session variable is only being set once. If I try to change it more than once, it reverts back to the first selection